# Having trouble getting button visibility to work with view binding

Tags: kotlin, visibility, android-viewbinding

Here is the github link:

https://github.com/dunow0033/BudgetTracker

Here is the XML for a button for updating a budget entry:

```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/updateBtn"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/green"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:text="Update Transaction"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the updateBtn at the bottom above has visibility set to gone.  I have an addTextChangedListener in a fragment with the following:

```
binding.labelInput.addTextChangedListener {
               updateBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
               if(it!!.isNotEmpty())
                   labelLayout.error = null
           }
```

And it's not making the button visible when I click on the input box to change it.  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Did you check if the text changed listener is actually being called?

Comment: Wow your question lead me to do some debugging, and I discovered that I had the addTextChangedListener inside another listener by mistake and so it wasn't being called.  I took the text changed listener out of where it was, and it started working....thank you!!